# Remove owl-item if it has no image inside

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I use owlCarousel for HTML below. Because I use ajax to show this HTML content, then for some reasons I cannot handle if which item has no image.

```
<div class="popular">
   <div class="item"><div class='item_inside'><img src="../img/p1.png"></div></div>
   <div class="item"><div class='item_inside'><!--No Image--></div></div>
   <div class="item"><div class='item_inside'><img src="../img/p2.png"></div></div>
   <div class="item"><div class='item_inside'><img src="../img/p3.png"></div></div>
</div>
```

I want to remove which item has no image, then I use `script` below but it seems that it removes all items.

```
$owl = $(".popular");
$owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(event){ 
    $('.item_inside').each(function(){
        if ($(this).find('img').length) {

        }else{
            $(this).closest('.owl-item').remove();
        }
    });
});
$owl.owlCarousel(
});
```

If I added it is inside window.load it does not work well. Sometimes, it fires and not working in Firefox.

Update1: My Ajax function calllike this.

```
$('.loadcontent').each(function(){
   ajaxfire();
   //this will append to popular section
}).promise().done(function(){ 
   $owl = $('.popular');
   $owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $(this).find('.item_inside:empty').each(function(idx, ele) {
        console.log('removed --> ' + $(this).closest('.owl-item').html());
        $(ele).closest('.owl-item').remove();
    });
   });
   $owl.owlCarousel();
   $owl.owlCarousel('update');
});
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your html the right selector is [:empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/).

You need to use [dom ready event](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(function () {
  ...put your code here....
})
```

```js
$owl = $(".popular");
$owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    $(this).find('.item_inside:empty').each(function (idx, ele) {
        console.log('removed --> ' + $(this).closest('.owl-item').html());
        $(ele).closest('.owl-item').remove();
    });
});
$owl.owlCarousel();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="popular">
    <div class="item">
        <div class='item_inside'><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class='item_inside'><!--No Image--></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class='item_inside'><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class='item_inside'><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying with your solution.

Comment: @gatenoM Maybe it is not working with Ajax. I updated question above. Can you please check again for solution? If all DOM loaded like your demo, it working well but with Ajax, it does not work. Thank you very much !

Comment: your issue, I assume, is in this selector **$('.popular');**. Because, I assume, you are appending new values I would suggest to use an unique ancestor like **$('#ancestor .popular');** Let me know, Thanks

Comment: I don't see **owlCarousel('update');** in the documentation. Instead I see this event **refresh.owl.carousel** If you are updating the carousel I assume you need to trigger such event. Let me know